# $\liminf P(X_n =k) \geq P(X=k)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, for integer valued random variables $X_n$and $X$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

$\liminf P(X_n =k) \geq P(X=k)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, for integer valued random variables $X_n$and $X$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

Since the random variables are integer valued, it’s sufficient to show $P(X_n =k) \to P(X=k)$ but I couldn’t show this. Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $\lim \inf \sum_{k\neq j} P(X_n=k) \geq \sum_{k\neq j} \lim \inf P(X_n=k)\geq \sum_{k\neq j} \lim \inf P(X=k)$ which gives $\lim \inf P(X_n \neq j) \geq \lim \inf P(X\neq j)$. This implies that  $\lim \sup P(X_n=j) \leq P(X=j)$. Finally, $P(X=j)\leq \lim \inf P(X_n=j)\leq \lim \sup P(X_n=j) \leq P(X=j)$ so $P(X_n=j) \to P(X=j)$ for each $j$.